# Is this a correct interpretation of k nearest neighbours?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

Given this dataset :

```
name1,name2,distance
a,b,1
a,c,5
b,c,8
```

If k=1 is the following correct :

```
a,b nearest neighbour is b,c
a,c nearest neighbour is b,c
b,c nearest neighbour is a,c
```

or

```
"a" nearest neighbor is b since distance(a,b) is 1 
"b" nearest neighbor is a since distance(a,b) is 1 
"c" nearest neighbor is a since distance(a,c) is 5
```

Comment: Pedantry alert: If your measure is symmetric, i.e., $d(a, b) = d(b, a)$ then your measure violates the triangle inequality, since $6 = d(b,a) + d(a,c) < d(b, c) = 8$, and isn't actually a valid distance, which can cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of k-nearest neigbors is which other point(s) are closest according to some distance metric.  The following holds for k=1.

The distance between $a$ and $b$ is 1, the distance between $a$ and $c$ is 5.  Thus the nearest neighbor to $a$ is $b$.

Similarly, the nearest neighbor to $b$ is $a$ since the distance between $b$ and $c$ is 8.

The nearest neighbor to $c$ is $a$ since the distance between $c$ and $a$ is 5 which is less than the distance between $c$ and $b$ which is 8.